# Initial size of heap memory for a program

Tags: c, linux, unix

Program:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<malloc.h>
main()
{
    int *i1, *i2;
    char *s;
    printf("sbrk(0) before malloc(4): %x\n", sbrk(0));
    i1 = (int *) malloc(sizeof(int));
    printf("sbrk(0) after `i1 = (int *) malloc(4)': %x\n", sbrk(0));
    i2 = (int *) malloc(sizeof(int));
    printf("sbrk(0) after `i2 = (int *) malloc(4)': %x\n", sbrk(0));
}
```

Output:

```
sbrk(0) before malloc(4): a027000
sbrk(0) after `i1 = (int *) malloc(4)': a048000
sbrk(0) after `i2 = (int *) malloc(4)': a048000
```

what is the initial size of the heap memory for the above program. I think, at the initial stage of the program, the starting and ending address of the
heap are same. Once, we call the malloc, it allocate memory using sbrk.

The above program shows that, at first sbrk(0) returns a027000 as program break. After the malloc statement is executed, the program break is changed
to a048000. It shows that, before calling malloc, the heap does not have
enough memory. So, only the program break is changed after calling malloc. At
initial state, if the heap had the enough memory, there is no need to change
the program break. So at first, the size of heap is zero. Is it right?

Comment: A good answer depends on the architecture - please tell us your OS and hardware.  Depending on your OS you probably have some kind of trace facility - you can run your program under the trace.  You will probably see calls to the brk() family of syscalls as part of start up. malloc uses binning of heap on some systems - meaning it has its own chunk of heap separate from libc.

Comment: Your `printf()`-specifiers are wrong. `%x` expects an argument of type `unsigned int`, while `sbrk()` returns a `void *`.

Comment: You also need to do is define when the "initial" size is to be measured.  Quite a bit of code can run before `main()` gets called.

Comment: I am using "Linux ltsp63 3.2.0-33-generic #52-Ubuntu SMP Thu Oct 18 16:19:45 UTC 2012 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux"

Answer (score 3):

When glibc debuginfo is installed (e.g. on Fedora 22: `dnf debuginfo-install glibc-2.21-5.fc22.x86_64`) one can print out the `main_arena` and `mp_`.

Debugging a program with an empty `int main(void)`:

`mp_.sbrk_base` is the base of the heap. On my Linux when `main` was called heap doesn't exist. After calling `malloc(1000)` `mp_.sbrk_base` is `0x602000`. `main_arena.top` is the free memory chunk at the top of heap. It is `0x6023f0`

```
(gdb) b main
Breakpoint 1 at 0x4004fa: file test.c, line 3.
(gdb) r 
Starting program: /home/m/a.out 

Breakpoint 1, main () at test.c:3
3       return 0;
(gdb) p mp_
$1 = {trim_threshold = 131072, top_pad = 131072, mmap_threshold = 131072, arena_test = 8, arena_max = 0, n_mmaps = 0, 
  n_mmaps_max = 65536, max_n_mmaps = 0, no_dyn_threshold = 0, mmapped_mem = 0, max_mmapped_mem = 0, max_total_mem = 0, 
  sbrk_base = 0x0}
(gdb) p main_arena 
$2 = {mutex = 0, flags = 0, fastbinsY = {0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0}, top = 0x0, 
  last_remainder = 0x0, bins = {0x0 <repeats 254 times>}, binmap = {0, 0, 0, 0}, next = 0x7ffff7dd6b20 <main_arena>, 
  next_free = 0x0, system_mem = 0, max_system_mem = 0}
(gdb) call malloc(1000)
$3 = (void *) 0x602010
(gdb) p mp_
$4 = {trim_threshold = 131072, top_pad = 131072, mmap_threshold = 131072, arena_test = 8, arena_max = 0, n_mmaps = 0, 
  n_mmaps_max = 65536, max_n_mmaps = 0, no_dyn_threshold = 0, mmapped_mem = 0, max_mmapped_mem = 0, max_total_mem = 0, 
  sbrk_base = 0x602000 ""}
    (gdb) p main_arena
$5 = {mutex = 0, flags = 1, fastbinsY = {0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0}, top = 0x6023f0, 
  last_remainder = 0x0, bins = {0x7ffff7dd6b78 <main_arena+88>, 0x7ffff7dd6b78 <main_arena+88>, [...]
0x7ffff7dd7198 <main_arena+1656>, 0x7ffff7dd71a8 <main_arena+1672>, 0x7ffff7dd71a8 <main_arena+1672>...}, binmap = {0, 
0, 0, 0}, next = 0x7ffff7dd6b20 <main_arena>, next_free = 0x0, system_mem = 135168, max_system_mem = 135168}

(gdb) call sbrk(0)
$6 = 6434816
(gdb) p (void*)$6
$7 = (void *) 0x623000
(gdb)
```

Answer (score 1):

What happens depends on what your O/S does before your `main()` is called.

On Mac OS X, there's a huge amount of memory allocation that occurs before your `main()` function gets called.  I currently have a list of 18 or so suppressed 'memory abuses' that are all from things that happen before the system-provided startup code calls `main()`.

Running a simple program that prints its arguments one per line, but giving it no arguments so there is no output, yields a usage report from [`valgrind`](http://valgrind.org/) like this:

```
==59405== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==59405== Copyright (C) 2002-2013, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==59405== Using Valgrind-3.11.0.SVN and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==59405== Command: /Users/jleffler/bin/al
==59405== 
--59405-- /Users/jleffler/bin/al:
--59405-- dSYM directory is missing; consider using --dsymutil=yes
--59405-- UNKNOWN mach_msg unhandled MACH_SEND_TRAILER option
--59405-- UNKNOWN mach_msg unhandled MACH_SEND_TRAILER option (repeated 2 times)
--59405-- UNKNOWN mach_msg unhandled MACH_SEND_TRAILER option (repeated 4 times)
==59405== 
==59405== HEAP SUMMARY:
==59405==     in use at exit: 34,808 bytes in 417 blocks
==59405==   total heap usage: 517 allocs, 100 frees, 41,784 bytes allocated
==59405== 
==59405== LEAK SUMMARY:
==59405==    definitely lost: 16 bytes in 1 blocks
==59405==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==59405==      possibly lost: 13,002 bytes in 109 blocks
==59405==    still reachable: 21,790 bytes in 307 blocks
==59405==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==59405== Rerun with --leak-check=full to see details of leaked memory
==59405== 
==59405== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==59405== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

The code for the program?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)  
{ 
    if (argc > 1)
    {
        while (*++argv) 
            puts(*argv);
    }
    return(EXIT_SUCCESS); 
}
```

Lots of memory activity, but none of it in the code I wrote.  The leak is one of a number that I have documented in a suppressions file.